# jQuery 'serialize' method not passing username to Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, methods, passwords

I am attempting to pass a bootstrapv4 modal username/password form to php using jQuery.
It is 'successful', but only partially, since it does not seem to work in Firefox.

In the html...

"signInForm" is the ID of the form.

"uName" (username) and "uPass" (password) are the 'name=' values of the 2 input fields on the form inside the modal

showStatus is the name of a div on the main page to update the status (I haven't gotten that to work), presumably because jQuery can't 'html' the div(?) *(NOTE: However, the (#showStatus)div is collapsing, which strongly suggests the script is at least working through to this point... since it is changing the html of the object!)*

Here is the jquery script on the page that loads the modal:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#signInForm").submit(function(event){
    submitForm();
    return false;
  });
});

  function submitForm(){
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "saveContact.php",
         cache:false,
         data: $('form#signInForm').serialize(),
         success: function(response){
             $("#showStatus").html(response)
             $("#signInModal").modal('hide');
         },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is saveContact.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['usrPass'])) {
   $name = strip_tags($_POST['usrName']);
   $user = strip_tags($_POST['usrPass']);
 }
?>
```

This seems to work in Chrome(OSX) and Safari (OSX). Both of these browsers will offer to 'save' the username/password combination (eg: "tony" and "car123") after the submit button on the modal is pressed and the modal fades away.

Here are two images showing the result:
[Google Chrome Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzoCj.png)

[Safari Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI9ta.png)

However - no matter what I have tried, I cannot get Firefox to accept the results coming from this script/modal. Here is what Firefox is doing....

[Firefox Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8T3u.png)

As can be seen, **Firefox is only saving the password and not the username**.
I have tried every single thing I can think of to solve this problem. It's especially annoying because it 'seems' to work.

I would be very very grateful for any help or assistance - this doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I noticed

- first, you mention want to show status on the page in a div and "showStatus is the name of a div" but in your success function you are referring it to as `id`. use `$('[name="showStatus"]')` instead
- second, you are not sending any response back from saveContact.php. Echo the status HTML in saveContact which will become the response for your success function.

As per firefox not skipping username in it's save password prompt, if your php is getting the values then this might be a browser issue. You can file an issue with Firefox

Comment: I'm afraid that MDN says that a <div> is not a validly named element. (ie: you do not say name='myDiv'). But you can give a div an id (id="myDiv").

Comment: I only said this because you mentioned your div have a name. But go with MDN and change the name to id